# Problem regarding 3.0's "hashlib" module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2to3

I've been working on getting a 2.5 module ported to 3.0, mostly for my own education, when I've gotten stuck. The class "Builder" has as its init:

```
def __init__(self, **options):
    self._verifyOptions(options)
    self._options = options
    self._initDigest()
    self._initBuildNames()
    self._methods = []
```

But the error occurs at:

```
def _initDigest(self):
    import os, sys, hashlib
    digester = hashlib.md5()
    digester.update(self._options.get('code'))
    self._digest = digester.hexdigest()
```

which has as its traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 5, in <module>
    """, language="Cee")
  File "C:\Python30\lib\site-packages\PyInline\__init__.py", line 31, in build
    b = m.Builder(**args)
  File "C:\Python30\lib\site-packages\PyInline\Cee.py", line 17, in __init__
    self._initDigest()
  File "C:\Python30\lib\site-packages\PyInline\Cee.py", line 27, in _initDigest
    digester.update(self._options.get('code'))
TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required
```

I've run it through 2to3, but it isn't picking up on it. As far as I can tell, the update function is expecting the argument to be in the form of bytes/buffer, but I've tried several different methods to convert it and haven't succeeded.

As always, any assistance would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that this line:

```
digester.update(self._options.get('code'))
```

should become:

```
digester.update(self._options.get('code').encode("utf-8"))
```

The actual desired encoding could be different in your case, but UTF-8 will work in all cases.

Comment: You have successfully corrected this error, and educated me further upon this task. I congratulate and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried 3.0 yet. But there is now a bigger distinction between a sequence of bytes and strings. The latter hold unicode codepoints while the former don't hold unicode but only `encoded` unicode strings. Hashes operate on sequences of bytes. So you will have to encode your (unicode) strings first bevore feeding them to a hash.